# Two app instances, same Relying Party in AD FS 2

Tags: asp.net, wif, adfs2.0

I currently have a copy of the app deployed to my local IIS as debug.wifclientapp.com and it will go to the ADFS server to authenticat but when it redirects after successful authentication it goes to www.wifclientapp.com which is the test instance on a remote server.

I setup the test instance first.  How can I get it to redirect back to the original site?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried going into:

ADFS Management > Trust relationships > Relying party trusts and check that the URL is correct in both the "Identifiers" and "Endpoint" tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy is correct. Your endpoint is most likely pointing to the test instance.